# 4.9.5 broke site behind load balancer, forwards to localhost

Tags: updates

I have 2 wordpress web servers behind a load balancer. When updating from 4.9.4 to 4.9.5, these sites broke if accessed from the main domain (but continue to be accessible if I use their alternate addresses which is obvi not possible for our end users). Instead of the site loading by going to the main domain `https://example.com`, everyone who accesses the domain is instead directed to `https://localhost`. As I said, if someone accessed `https://wp1.example.com` or `https://wp2.example.com`, the sites work. For now, I have reverted to 4.9.4 which fixes the problem, but I would like to figure out a long term fix. Any suggestions?

FYI inside my wp-config files I am using these directives:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

**UPDATE:**
I think I found the reason this is happening (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/42894) but still have no workable fix.

Comment: it's probably the defines in your `wp-config.php` that have done that, all it takes is a loopback request that also sets DB options. Are they really necessary?

Comment: if it is the defines, how might I fix them and still respect multiple domain url access for my sites? (ie example.com as well as wp1.example.com)

Comment: Did you try `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];` instead of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`
Nice explanation:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2297421/1321398

Comment: you should look into domain mapping plugins

Comment: @Pabamato does SERVER_NAME work for multiple domains? If not it is a non-starter as I need to be able to access the site using multiple domains.

Comment: @Stephen it's server side config, you can have a diff/same one on each server, if your site right now is working for the `WP_SITEURL` value and the `DB` one, I believe it won't make a difference. The problem may be the value from the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` constant

Comment: Thanks, I think your suggestion could work if I also do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31479341/nginx-server-directive-with-multiple-server-name-entries-always-first-one-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with some thanks to @Pabamato, I was able to work around this and update to 4.9.5 by changing my wp-config directives to:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

And also adding a param to my nginx conf to properly account for variable server names:

```
fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
```

without both of the above, my particular setup would not work properly.

**UPDATE**: spoke too soon, all kinds of badly formatted page if connecting to load balancer, despite ssl insecure content fixer. Reverted to 4.9.4 and undid changes and problem went away. still looking for a complete solution...

**UPDATE 2**: I think I have finally isolated my last problems to being related to permalink issues. Clearing those this now all seems to work (at least in my test environment), so I will mark this as the solution after all.

**UPDATE 3**: I was wrong, clearing permalinks did not work, it only seemed like it did on my test site (test.example.com) where in fact it was working because all subdomains work (ie test.example.com, www.example.com, etc) whereas the main domain would NOT work no matter what I did. So forcing my site to always use www subdomain works, but sucks and I have no idea why still. In any event, here is my new code for wp-config that is working:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'wp1.example.com') {
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://wp1.example.com');
    define('WP_HOME', 'https://wp1.example.com');
  } else {
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.example.com');
    define('WP_HOME', 'https://www.example.com');
  }
```